# dojo.require() (1.4.3) - Force js file refresh

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am using a version query param to force refresh my js files (script.js?ver=)

My problem is that I can't use this approach for custom dojo classes loaded using dojo.require()

Is there a way to force a refresh when using require()? (unless there's some other way to include dojo classes)

---------edit-------------

I added cacheBust as suggested and started receiving "could not load.. "

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://host/dev/dojolib.nsf/dojo/dojo.js' 
djConfig="cacheBust:'ver=1', baseUrl:'https://host/dev/dojolib.nsf/dojo/'">
</script>
```

Comment: Later versions have the `cacheBust` config value, but [this doesn't appear to be supported in 1.4.3](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.4.3/cheat.html).

Comment: i added cachebust to djConfig and started getting "Could not load 'dojo.nls.dojo_en-gb" Once i rename it to xBust, the errors go away.. so it seems like cacheBust is being recognized by dojo.. but it's not working

Comment: Problem is with domino.. first query param must be ?OpenFileResource  ....tried setting the cachebust value to ?OpenFileResource&ver=1.0 , but dojo removes any special chars (? & = .)